# swift splitview controller default cell

Tags: swift, ipad, ios8, uisplitviewcontroller

I am currently working on a project with a split view controller using swift in xcode6.

I currently have it so that when the app loads it remembers which cell you previously had selected and will "select" that cell. However when the cell is selected it doesn't initiate the segue to the detail view controller loading that cells related information.

This is my master view controller code, wondering what I can add to initate the segue for the selected cell when the app loads?

```
class MasterViewController: UITableViewController {

var detailViewController: DetailViewController? = nil
var titles = [String]()
var ageGroups = [String]()
var danceForms = [String]()
var danceDivisions = [String]()
var danceCategories = [String]()
var routineIds = [Int]()



override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false
    self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 320.0, height: 600.0)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([rightAddBarButtonItem,rightSearchBarButtonItem], animated: true)





    let query = PFQuery(className: "Schedule")
    query.orderByAscending("routineId")
    query.whereKey("eventId", equalTo: 16)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

        if let objects = objects {


            for object in objects {

                self.titles.append(object["title"] as! String)
                self.ageGroups.append(object["ageGroup"] as! String)
                self.danceForms.append(object["danceForm"] as! String)
                self.danceDivisions.append(object["danceDivision"] as! String)
                self.danceCategories.append(object["danceCategory"] as! String)
                self.routineIds.append(object["routineId"] as! Int)



                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                    var returnValue: Int? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("selectedCell") as? Int
                    if let value = returnValue{

                    }
                    else{
                        returnValue = 1;
                    }
                    if  returnValue! > self.routineIds.count{
                        returnValue = 1;
                    }
                    let rowToSelect:NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: returnValue!-1, inSection: 0);  //slecting 0th row with 0th section
                    self.tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(rowToSelect, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None);

                })




            }


        }
    }







}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


// MARK: - Segues


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
            let object = routineIds[indexPath.row] as Int
            let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController
            controller.detailItem = object
            controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem()
            controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Table View

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return titles.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("scheduleCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! scheduleCell

    var myCustomSelectionColorView = UIView()
    myCustomSelectionColorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = myCustomSelectionColorView



    cell.routineId.text = "\(routineIds[indexPath.row])"
    cell.routineTitle.text = titles[indexPath.row]
    cell.routineAgeGroup.text = " - \(ageGroups[indexPath.row])"
    cell.routineDanceForm.text = " - \(danceForms[indexPath.row])"
    cell.routineDivision.text = danceDivisions[indexPath.row]
    cell.routineCategory.text = danceCategories[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.

    return false
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    println(routineIds[indexPath.row])
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(routineIds[indexPath.row], forKey: "selectedCell")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    var returnValue: Int? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("selectedCell") as? Int
    if returnValue! == 1{

    }

    println(returnValue)

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initiate a segue manually with the [performSegueWithIdentifier](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:) method on UIViewController.

```
// in your dispatch_async block:
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetail", self)
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be initiating the segue, and passing the data over but i'm getting another error now... If I try to print a value that was passed along 

 `println(object["title"] as! String)` 

it works... But if I try to assign that same value directly afterwards to a label as text:
`self.rITitle.text = (object["title"] as! String)`

It fails saying "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Why would the value be ok to println but would fail to assign to a label?

Comment: If you try to access views in the destination view controller in the performSegue method, they might be nil. You will probably need to add an instance variable to your destination view controller that includes all the data you want to show on it. I suggest refactoring your titles array, age groups array, etc. into a single array of some DanceGroup type that has a title, age group, etc. and then pass an instance of DanceGroup to your detail view controller. In viewDidLoad, check for that variable and populate the views with it if it's non-nil.

Comment: Figured it out, because my dispatch_async was in a for loop, I had to check that the selected index was == the current loops index so that it would only attempt to pass the correct data over to the detailView instead of passing multiple rows of nil, and a single correct row... 

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to take advantage of [state restoration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforImplementingYourApp/StrategiesforImplementingYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW2).  The benefit is that the application can restore each view controller's state, without you having to code or handle much of what you're doing now.

State restoration will save and load application state for you, freeing you from having to preserve details in `NSUserDefaults`, such as which cell was selected.  The SDK actually preserves a wide range of useful details, such as whether your `splitViewController` was collapsed or expanded, whether a navigation bar was compact or hidden, etc.  These are all nice touches, and you get them for free when you use state restoration.

To take advantage of state restoration, you'd:

1. Have your `AppDelegate` implement `application:shouldSaveApplicationState:` and `application:shouldRestoreApplicationState:`
2. Assign restoration identifiers to each view controller you want to preserve.  You can easily do this in Storyboard.
3. Show your app's window from `application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.
4. Encode and decode state of view controllers using `encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:` and `decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:`

Another benefit is that a view controller can save its own details about which object it was displaying, without another view controller needing to perform any segue (or pass any details).  It allows your view controllers to be more self-contained, and less tightly coupled to other view controllers.

State restoration really cuts down on the amount of code you have to write, which pays off in the long run, having to maintain, support, and upgrade apps.